# Visual Studio 2008 Navigate Forewards/Backwards Buttons Don't Work As Expected

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I just installed VS2008 on my new Win7 box. I have Navigate Backwards and Navigate Forwards buttons on my tool bar. When I change between documents, I do NOT see a list drop down for each of the buttons like should be seen here after opening multiple documents and switching between their methods:

[How it should work.](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/image.axd?picture=navigation_history.jpg)

Instead, I just see the buttons without drop downs. I find that navigating forwards and backwards doesn't work as it should. I should be able to click in different lines of the code and press the nav back/forwards buttons to jump between lines. This is not the case.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

PS - I installed SP1 just to see and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may not be two helpful, but I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Window 7 and they work ask expected.  The drop downs work like in your screenshot.

I think you may have some odd conflict, the only think I can think is two things:

1) Go to Programs and Features and then click "View installed updates" in the upper left area. After it finishes loading, enter "Microsoft Visual Studio" in the search box in the upper right area. Depending on how patched your system is, you should have a number of patches listed here.  I would uninstall each on of them ONE AT A TIME reboot and then try the navigate feature again. If it works you found your conflict, if not repeat this process until either you find the conflict on until you run out of updates to uninstall.  If you run out then you can have to try the second option below.

2) Uninstall and re-install everything.  Make sure you uninstall any Visual Studio updates (see #1 above on how), then the Service Pack, and last the program itself.  Once its completely uninstalled reboot.  Then install it clean, do not apply any updates just the latest service pack.  If it works then great, you can apply each update from windows update at a time testing after each one to make sure you don't re-introduce it.  If it comes back, just back out the update and contract Microsoft via their website to report the problem with the update.

If none of the above works and you still have an issue, I am afraid the conflict is from a 3rd party application or driver which makes the scope much more difficult to trouble shoot.

If this is the case then if you are using an OEM version of Windows and you still have a Warranty with your computer manufacture then give them a call and let them know what the problem is and what you have already tried.  Make sure you let them know that other people with Windows 7 are not having this problem, to help prevent them from blaming the application and not helping you.

If you have a retail copy of Windows 7 then you should still be within the support period and can contact Microsoft OS support directly, the phone number should be in the retail box you purchased.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't fix anything at all. I applied all service packs, reinstalled, reset all settings etc.

This works perfectly FINE on my WinXP box... :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to Tools > Import and Export Settings. I followed the wizard and choose to import the Visual C# Development Settings. I'm not sure if the other settings will work, but the C# ones worked for me.